# Post call to controller method also calls other post method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

This question is part for clarification

I have following methods in my Library controller.

**LibraryController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Settings{
    //code here
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Settings{
    //code here
}

public PartialViewResult VerifyBookByISBN()
{
    //Code here
}
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult VerifyBookByISBN(Guid libraryid, long isbn)
{
    //Code here
}
```

**Settings View**

```
{ Html.RenderAction("VerifyBookByISBN", "Library"); }
<Form id="SettingFormId">
    //settings form code here
</Form>
```

**VerifyBookByISBN view**

```
<Form id="VerifyBookByISBNFormId">
    //code here
</Form>
```

Settings view contains `VerifyBookByISBN partialView` and setting view and `VerifyBookByISBN(partailView)`, and both have a form.
When setting form is submitted it's `POST` method is called but after that `VerifyBookByISBN(POST)` is also called which I wasn't expecting, resulting into error since argument wasn't passed.

When I changed `VerifyBookByISBN(POST)` to `VerifyBookByISBNNew(POST)` things are working fine.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult VerifyBookByISBNNew(Guid libraryid, long isbn)
{
    //Code here
}
```

My confusion is, if we have such scenario where we have a partial-view (having Form) in a View(having Form) we should not keep it's Post method name same as it's name right?

Let me know if I made some wrong

Comment: Have you tried setting `action` attribute on both the forms? Also, is there only one button on the page doing submit and that is outside of both the `form` tags?

Comment: yes i have set action attribute for both and both form have different submit inside their form Tag.